# PHP - Merge two arrays (same-length) into one associative?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, associative-array

pretty straightforward question actually..

> **is it possible in PHP to combine two separate arrays of the same length to one associative array where the values of the first array are used as keys in the associative array?**

I could ofcourse do this, but I'm looking for another (built-in) function, or more efficient solution..?

```
function Combine($array1, $array2) {
    if(count($array1) == count($array2)) {
        $assArray = array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++) {
            $assArray[$array1[$i]] = $array2[$i];
        }
        return $assArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: "ass array", definitely an easy to recall name. ;)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[`array_combine($keys, $values)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

PS: Click on my answer! Its also a link!

Answer (score 16):

you need [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

There’s already an [`array_combine` function](http://docs.php.net/array_combine):

```
$combined = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: but array combine dosn't take null values into a new array. :(

Comment: @gumuruh Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2):

**hello everybody i will show you how to merge 2 arrays in one array**

we have 2 arrays and i will make one array from them

```
 $data_key  = array('key1','key2');
 $data_value = array('val1','val2');
```

lets declare the main array

```
$main_array = array();
```

now let's fill it with the 2 arrays

```
foreach ($data_key as $i => $key) {
         $main_array[$key] = $data_value[$i];
}
```

now let's see the result  by using `var_dump($main_array);`

```
array(2) { 
["key1"]=> string(4) "val1"
["key2"]=> string(4) "val2" 
}
```

**i hope that can help someone :)**