# array(a,b,c) + array(1,2,3) to array(a=>1, b=>2,c=>3)

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 same-length arrays and I want to merge them into first array as keys and second array as values.

```
array(a,b,c) + array(1,2,3) to array(a=>1, b=>2,c=>3)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Merge two arrays (same-length) into one associative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200885/php-merge-two-arrays-same-length-into-one-associative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 <?php
    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    $b = array(1, 2, 3);
    $c = array_combine($a, $b);

    print_r($c);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a built in function in php for this called [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$arr1 = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3);
$result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: btw, next time you're trying to do something with an array look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php Odds are there's a built in function for it, with a name that describes it fairly well. I didn't know the function existed until I saw your question. I just looked in the reference...

Comment: totally agree, I fail to understand how questions like this get upvoted.