# Storing and retrieving an associative arry in MySQL DB with the use of a form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

Ok, I have removed my php code which wasn't ok and rephrase what I'm looking for. Here I go...

Can I combine two arrays in 1 associative array?

```
$a = array("11", "22", "111");
$b = array("50", "30", "20");
```

I want both arrays to be combined in a new associative array as folows:

```
$appended = array ("11" => "50", "22" => "30", "111" => "20");
```

So, what I want to do is put the key from variable "$a" and the value from variable "$b"...

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I think it might be an idea to throw away this code and start over. Forget about the PHP for the time being. Instead, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Are you talking about this? [Merge two arrays (same-length) into one associative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200885/php-merge-two-arrays-same-length-into-one-associative) You know the **search won't bite or take a piece of you away**, just give it a try :)! You waited 5 hours for something you would have spent less than 5 minutes to find :P

Comment: I was just reading the topic when you answered prix, coïncidence... My original post was relatively different though, hence the 5 hours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function:

```
$appended = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Comment: Thank you Zsolt, you won the prize as being the only one who answered 100% on-topic on my question! I almost got the impression that asking questions here is a dangerous undertaking...