# PHP array return values only

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I've begun study of PHP Object oriented programming.
I have limited experience with PHP in general.

I have PHP code as follows:

A "Cars" class:

```
class Cars {
    static $car_specs = array("wheel_count", "name", "color");
    static function set_car_detail() {
        self::$car_specs["wheel_count"] = 4;
        self::$car_specs["name"] = "default";
        self::$car_specs["color"] = "generic";
    }
    static function get_car_detail() {
        return self::$car_specs;
    }
}
```

and then I am trying to output this:

```
Cars::set_car_detail();
echo implode(',', Cars::get_car_detail());
```

the echo is :

```
wheel_count,name,color,4,default,generic
```

however I'm trying to get:

```
4,default,generic
```

foreach attempts yielded similar responses.
I wish to understand what is it I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is not OOP- you should use getter/setter instead of putting every property into 1 array + also no need for static

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Merge two arrays (same-length) into one associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200885/php-merge-two-arrays-same-length-into-one-associative)

Comment: Why do you set the details in a separate function? In the future, are you planning to pass in those values? Otherwise, it does not make sense as to why you would not create the already hydrated array.

Comment: The `Cars` "class" is not a class at all. It works more like a namespace. Avoid static members and methods. They are global objects with fancy names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is not a class at all. It is just a bunch of global functions and variables with funky names. Try to avoid static properties and methods as they are not OOP. Also try to avoid public properties and getters/setters as they are just procedural programming in disguise.

A skeleton of a `Car` class could look like this:

```
class Car {
    private $wheel_count;
    private $name;
    private $color;

    public function __construct($wheel_count, $name, $color)
    {
        $this->wheel_count = $wheel_count;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function paint($new_color)
    {
        $this->color = $new_color;
    }

    public function describe()
    {
        return sprintf('%d wheels, %s %s', $this->wheel_count, $this->color, $this->name);
    }
}
```

The object properties are private. Encapsulation is one of the key concepts of OOP. They are set in the constructor. The role of the constructor is to initialize the object, to make it ready to work. Make sure the constructor initializes all object's properties and it doesn't do anything else (no work in the constructor.)

Create methods in the class for the actions that make sense for your class. For example, the number of wheels of a car never changes, there is no point in writing a method to set a different number of wheels. But the color of the car sometimes changes and the `paint()` method handles that.

Avoid writing "getters" (i.e. methods that do nothing than returning the value of a property). They are the sign that some code that belongs to the class is written somewhere outside the class (and many times it is duplicated here and there and everywhere, with minor or no changes). Whenever is possible and appropriate, write a method that uses the object's properties to generate an useful value (as opposed to writing getters to let the useful value be computed somewhere else).

This is how the `Car` class described below is used:

```
$car1 = new Car(4, 'Mazda', 'red');
$car2 = new Car(8, 'big truck', 'blue');

echo($car1->describe());
# 4 wheels, red Mazda

$car1->paint('green');
echo($car1->describe());
# 4 wheels, green Mazda
```

Comment: Thank you.your reply was most informative.
I do agree that the class provided was not really a class...my focus was on that time on how static variables and functions work.

Comment: Static properties are just global variables with complicate names (and visibility constraints). They are not inherited; you can access a static variable (`Cars::$car_specs`) from a class that extends `Cars` using `self::$car_specs` but, unless you (re-)declare the property in the child class, `self::$car_specs` in the child class is the same thing as `Cars::$car_specs`. This is a counter-intuitive behaviour that leads to confusion and errors. Static methods are just global functions with complicate names (and visibility constraints).

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized the array with values, but perhaps you want to initialize it with keys:

```
static $car_specs = array(
    "wheel_count" => null, 
    "name" => null, 
    "color" => null
);
```

Comment: I see how this working but unsure why compare to what I wrote?
I assume I am doing a bad practice when I initialize an array with just keys and later add them values?

Comment: @AviE.Koenig: Sure, you are right. Just it is one of possible answers for the question "what is it I am doing wrong".

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an array of `key` values, why don't you create a corresponding array of `values` for each key and use `array_combine()`.

```
class Cars {
    static $car_specs;

    static function set_car_detail() {
        $keys = array("wheel_count", "name", "color");
        $values = array(4, "default", "generic");

        self::$car_specs = array_combine($keys, $values);
    }

    static function get_car_detail() {
        return self::$car_specs;
    }
}

Cars::set_car_detail();
echo implode(',', Cars::get_car_detail());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a self-explanatory function specifically for that

```
   static function get_car_detail() {
      return array_values(self::$car_specs);
   }
```

Comment: `implode` already operates only on array values, that's not what the problem is here