# how to get two columns value in laravel where first is key and 2nd is value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 columns `id = [10 , 22 , 31];`
and `loction_url = [123.456 , 654.325 , 632,983];`
i want data into a single array like this `$a = [10 => 123.456 , 22 => 654.325 , 31 => 632,983];`

here is my query which only gets columns

```
$customers = Customer::whereIn('created_by', $adminot)->select(array('id' , 'location_url'))->get();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Merge two arrays (same-length) into one associative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200885/php-merge-two-arrays-same-length-into-one-associative)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what [Collection::pluck](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_pluck) is for:

```
$customers = Customer::whereIn('created_by', $adminot)
    ->select(array('id' , 'location_url'))
    ->get()
    ->pluck('location_url', 'id');
```

It'll return an associative array where the key is the value of `id` and it's respective value is the value of `location_url`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_merge like

```
$a = array_merge($id,$loction_url)
```